# Which model behind SequencePredictorFunction?

Tags: machine-learning, implementation-details, markov-chains

Is the `SequencePredictorFunction` based on Hidden Markov Model?
If so, how does the model estimate the number of hidden states?

Comment: Wolfram doesn't always documents the *Method* behind a function, and rarely if ever documents the details of the method implementation. How far did you go trying to find the answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MarkovLanguageModelUsingBackoff`

You can see the code:

```
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@SequencePredict
```

[image]

[KenLM Language Model Toolkit](https://kheafield.com/code/kenlm/)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Extended comment...

From the Wolfram Documentation, the

> `SequencePredictorFunction[...]` represents a function generated by
> `SequencePredict` that predicts the next elements from a sequence.

So best to look at `SequencePredict`

`SequencePredict` includes settings for the option "Method".

[image]

Additionally, the language does include:

[image]

which might prove useful to you.

More information on your specific application, will likely attract more answers.